# How to add custom middleware to Laravel Nova

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova, laravel-middleware

I am not 100% expert with Laravel routes, so I am finding some issues trying to accomplish the following:

- on each an every Nova page requested, I need to first verify that a token is obtained and valid on an external service (it expires every 30').
- I have a controller handle managing that and working fine. My problem is that I don't hit the nail with adding this verification to a middleware.
- In other words, before displaying any Nova view, I need to check that this token is not expired. If it is, I post a call and refresh it.

I've googled around and found no similar question/issue.
Anyone can give me an enlighting example?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I found the place while looking at another post here.
What I was missing was to declare my token validator class in config/nova.php

Here:

```
`/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Nova Route Middleware
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| These middleware will be assigned to every Nova route, giving you the
| chance to add your own middleware to this stack or override any of
| the existing middleware. Or, you can just stick with this stack.
|
*/

'middleware' => [
    'web',
    Authenticate::class,
    DispatchServingNovaEvent::class,
    BootTools::class,
    Authorize::class,
    HereShouldGoMyClass::class,
],`
```